# Lightweight SharpKeys replacement

Tags: windows, keyboard, remapping

I was looking for a tool to help me remap my Caps Lock to another key and came across [SharpKeys](http://www.codeplex.com/sharpkeys). It's a handy tool but installing the entire .NET framework for this tiny utility seems like overkill. Are there any lighter alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never even explored alternatives to [SharpKeys](http://www.codeplex.com/sharpkeys).  Before I stumbled across it, I used to do all my scan code mapping by hand.  I never noticed it required the .NET framework until just now; honestly, I can't see a huge downside to having the framework installed.

At the end of the day, mapping utilities are just slick UIs that edit a registry key.  If you know the [scan codes](http://web.archive.org/web/20111129061431/http://www.usnetizen.com/fix_capslock.php) for the keys you want to map, you can just do the registry edit yourself.

For example, this maps Caps Lock to Left Shift:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,2a,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: I beg to differ! autohotkey doesn't edit registry keys (unless you tell it to)...