# Location of Hot Keys in Windows

Tags: windows, hotkeys

I was wondering if anyone knew where the location of the hot key commands were for Windows? Is it like a script saved on the hard drive or is it at the OS level? I wanted to make custom hot keys for my computer. Thanks!

Comment: See also ["Is there any way to get a list of the system-wide keyboard shortcuts currently in use?"](http://superuser.com/questions/298484/) and ["Keyboard shortcut helper app for windows?"](http://superuser.com/questions/299197/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Will require a little reading of the [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro) but it's a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

The most common tool for this is Sharpkeys [see this answer for more information](http://www.superuser.com/questions/10961/lightweight-sharpkeys-replacement).

Comment: does Sharpkeys allow rebinding of key commands? I thought it just remapped keys 1:1.